# Updating PHP from 5.4 to 5.6 broke

Tags: 7

My ISP updated PHP from 5.4 to 5.6 and my Drupal 7 site broke. Normal pages have mysql errors, and update.php says I need to install a PDO connector.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Your host (or someone with server access) needs to install and enable the PDO and PDO MySQL extensions in PHP by the sounds of it

Comment: My ISPO says: PHP version 5.6 does not support PDO extension, but PHP 5.4 already has PDO extension.